# Little vs Big Endianess: How to interpret the test

Tags: c, endianness

So I'm writing a program to test the endianess of a machine and print it.
I understand the difference between little and big endian, however, from what I've found online, I don't understand why these tests show the endianess of a machine.

This is what I've found online. What does *(char *)&x mean and how does it equaling one prove that a machine is Little-Endian?

```
int x = 1;
if (*(char *)&x == 1) {
    printf("Little-Endian\n");
} else {
    printf("Big-Endian\n");
}
```

Comment: If you "already understand" the difference between big and little endian, why then is a basic test of endianess not understandable?

Comment: I know what it does and am not entirely sure why checking if a dereferenced version of the variable, cast as a pointer to a char will tell you that.  Unless the endianness of a char is standard, in which case it'll tell you if it changes during that bitwise-cast.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we split into different parts:

1. `&x`: This gets the address of the location where the variable `x` is, i.e. `&x` is a pointer to `x`. The type is `int *`.
2. `(char *)&x`: This takes the address of `x` (which is a `int *`) and converts it to a `char *`.
3. `*(char *)&x`: This dereferences the `char *` pointed to by `&x`, i.e. gets the values stored in `x`.

Now if we go back to `x` and how the data is stored. On most machines, `x` is four bytes. Storing `1` in `x` sets the least significant bit to `1` and the rest to `0`. On a little-endian machine this is stored in memory as `0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00`, while on a big-endian machine it's stored as `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01`.

What the expression does is get the first of those bytes and check if it's `1` or not.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what the memory will look like, assuming a 32b integer:

```
Little-endian
0x01000000 = 00000001000...00

Big-endian
0x00000001 = 0......01
```

Dereferencing a `char *` gives you one byte. Your test fetches the first byte at that memory location by **interpreting the address as a `char *`** and then dereferencing it.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Could be. What do you mean ?

Comment: Maybe I am confused, are you using `0x80000000` as the byte address in memory?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I'm using it to represent the number `2^31` in base 16.

Comment: @cnicutar: The value will actually be stored as 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, not 0x80000000.  The bits aren't reversed in the byte -- just the order of bytes stored in memory.

Comment: See @Sangeeth Saravanaraj's answer for a better description of how the value is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down `*(char *)&x`:

`&x` is the address of integer x

`(char *)` causes address of integer x to be treated as an address of a character (aka byte)

`*` references the value of the byte

Comment: Obviously @Joahcim Pileborg explained it better and quicker.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x;
```

`x` is a variable which can hold a 32-bit value.

```
int x = 1;
```

A given hardware can store the value `1` as a `32-bit` value in one of the following format.

```
Little Endian
0x100    0x101    0x102    0x103
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 

(or) 

Big Endian
0x100    0x101    0x102    0x103
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

Now lets try to break the expression:

```
&x
```

Get the address of variable `x`. Say the address of `x` is `0x100`.

```
(char *)&x
```

`&x` is an address of an integer variable. `(char *)&x` converts the address `0x100` from `(int *)` to `(char *)`.

```
*(char *)&x
```

de-references the value stored in the `(char *)` which is nothing but the first byte (from left to right) in the 4-byte (32-bit integer `x`).

```
(*(char *)&x == 1)
```

If the first byte from left to right stores the value `00000001`, then it is little endian. If the 4th byte from left to right stores value `00000001`, then it is big endian.

Comment: thank you! I have another quick question, if you don't mind. Will (char *)&x give me a string of the address of x? Also, how can I get the value of all individual bits in a variable? An entire byte per say.

Comment: A loose definition of a C-string is - "one or more (array of) characters (char) which are terminated by '\0'". In C, a string can be represented as `char x[]` or `char *x`.

Comment: For bit operations, please refer http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that answers the question.  Here's a more general answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"sizeof(char) = "<<sizeof(char)<<endl;
cout<<"sizeof(unsigned int) = "<<sizeof(unsigned int)<<endl;
//NOTE: Windows, Mac OS, and Linux and Tru64 Unix are Little Endian architectures
//Little Endian means the memory value increases as the digit significance increases
//Proof for Windows: 

unsigned int x = 0x01020408; //each hexadecimal digit is 4 bits, meaning there are 2
                             //digits for every byte
char *c = (char *)&x;
unsigned int y = *c*pow(16,0) +pow(16,2) * *(c+1)+pow(16,4) * *(c+2)+pow(16,6) * *(c+3);
//Here's the test: construct the sum y such that we select subsequent bytes of 0x01020408
//in increasing order and then we multiply each by its corresponding significance in
//increasing order.  The convention for hexadecimal number definitions is that  
//the least significant digit is at the right of the number.  
//Finally, if (y==x),then...     
if (y==x) cout<<"Little Endian"<<endl;
else cout<<"Big Endian"<<endl;

cout<<(int) *c<<endl;
cout<<(int) *(c+1)<<endl;
cout<<(int) *(c+2)<<endl;
cout<<(int) *(c+3)<<endl;
cout<<"x is "<<x<<endl;
cout<<(int)*c<<"*1 + "<<(int)*(c+1)<<"*16^2 + "<<(int)*(c+2)<<"*16^4 + "<<(int)*(c+3)<<" *16^6 = "<<y<<endl;
system("PAUSE"); //Only include this on a counsel program
return 0;
}
```

This displays
8
4
2
1
for the dereferenced values at c, c+1, c+2, and c+3 respectively.
The sum y is 16909320, which is equal to x.  Even though the significance of the digits grow from right-to-left, this is still Little Endian because the corresponding memory values also grow from right-to-left, which is why the left-shift binary operator << would increase a variable's value until non-zero digits are shifted off the variable altogether.  Don't confuse this operator with std::cout's << operator.
If this were Big Endian, then the display for c, c+1, c+2, and c+3 respectively would look like:
1
2
4
8

Answer (score 0):

If a big-endian 4-byte unsigned integer looks like 0xAABBCCDD which is equal to 2864434397, then that same 4-byte unsigned integer looks like 0xDDCCBBAA on a little-endian processor which is also equal to 2864434397.

If a big-endian 2-byte unsigned short looks like 0xAABB which is equal to 43707, then that same 2-byte unsigned short looks like 0xBBAA on a little-endian processor which is also equal to 43707.

Here are a couple of handy #define functions to swap bytes from little-endian to big-endian and vice-versa -->

```
// can be used for short, unsigned short, word, unsigned word (2-byte types)
#define BYTESWAP16(n) (((n&0xFF00)>>8)|((n&0x00FF)<<8))

// can be used for int or unsigned int or float (4-byte types)
#define BYTESWAP32(n) ((BYTESWAP16((n&0xFFFF0000)>>16))|((BYTESWAP16(n&0x0000FFFF))<<16))

// can be used for unsigned long long or double (8-byte types)
#define BYTESWAP64(n) ((BYTESWAP32((n&0xFFFFFFFF00000000)>>32))|((BYTESWAP32(n&0x00000000FFFFFFFF))<<32))
```