# big endian vs little endian

Tags: c++, endianness

i work on a 64 bit intel processor...i was learning about big and little endian and what i understood was that these are byte orderings within a word such that in a 64 bit data, msb will have lowest address in big endian form and the highest address in little endian form...now i have a problem:

I wrote [this code](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=frFkl)
to determine whether my processor was little or big endian...
I input

```
0102030405060708 (this is in hex)
```

and hoped to get `08` and `07` and `06` and... and `01` as answer

but instead got `0` and `25` and `50` and `-125` and `-13` and `501` and `-41` and `66`.
when I wrote the same code taking 's' as 2 byte(short), the output for `0102` was `2` and `1` (which is in accordance with little endian)...so what went wrong here?

Comment: When you write your question, note that it shows a preview of what it's going to look like. Please use that to ensure that your question looks *readable*. Thank you :)

Comment: What do you expect to be the bit-code of a double that represents 0x0102030405060708?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9971369/440558) for a question containing a method to find the endianess.

Comment: char is a signed type. Use unsigned char if you don't want the negative numbers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code isn't included and the link has expired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing your input value as a `double`, which stores the value as a [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) value. Try using a `long long` instead, which is a 64 bit integer, and should store the value as you expect.

Comment: if my word is of 64 bit and there was a data type 9 byte long and i set it to 0x010203040506070809...and follow the same procedure...would i see 09 and 08 and 07... and 02? where would 01 go....lowest address byte or highest address byte of next word?

Comment: @avinash It's impossible to store a 9byte data type in 8byte, hence before even storing it, it would usually throw a compile time error (well or you get some kind of truncation, which usually means you lose the higher byte that can't be represented)

Answer (score 2):

Taking a hex number into a `(double)` is not likely to do what you expect; it's a floating point value consisting of a base 2 mantissa and exponent.  You might find `(long)` or `(long long)` to be closer to what you intended.