# Test big endian

Tags: c, gcc, endianness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Little vs Big Endianess: How to interpret the test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971369/little-vs-big-endianess-how-to-interpret-the-test)

Is there an easy method to test code with gcc or any online compiler like ideone for big endian? I don't want to use qemu or virtual machines

**EDIT**

Can someone explain the behavior of this piece of code on a system using big endian?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
    int32_t i;
    unsigned char u[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

    memcpy(&i, u, sizeof(u));
    printf("%d\n", i);
    memcpy(u, &i, sizeof(i));
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%c", u[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Include `endian.h` and try something like `if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN`

Comment: multiarch on Debian/Ubuntu makes qemu much simpler than you think...

Comment: It's almost 100% certain that any online "compiler farm" is x86-based. It's terribly expensive to buy anything else...

Comment: @mats: that is not necessarily true, as the powerpc is also a cheap (more or less) "farm-platform"

Comment: I suggest writing code that doesn't care about the underlying byte order of integers...

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Not always possible.  I don't know if that's the case here though.

Comment: @EdS. Nonsense. In which situation is the underlying byte order of integers important to an algorithm? How does the underlying byte order impact upon the ability to encode the integer value using an abstract representation (eg. a string of decimal digits), or to decode that abstract representation?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Really?  Not all programming is done via abstract representations.  Where do you think those abstractions come from?  Programmers write them.  Hell, I had to write a conversion routine literally last week.  Nothing fancy, just writing out some 16 bpp image data via libtiff, which expects big endian.

Comment: @EdS. C is described in terms of semantics on an abstract machine. Please explain to me, which aspect of the following code, which portably encodes and decodes big endian representations of integers, cares about the underlying representation of a uint16: `void deserialise_uint16(uint16_t *dest, uint8_t *src) { *dest = src[0] << 8 + src[1]; }` `void serialise_uint16(uint8_t *dest, uint16_t src) { dest[0] = src >> 8; dest[1] = src & 0xFF; }`

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Ummm... obviously this part cares; `*dest = src[0] << 8 + src[1];`.  I'm not sure what you're arguing.  That code didn't spring up magically out of nowhere, and, *gasp*, whomever wrote it needed to know that the bytes of `src` needed to be swapped.  Next, you would only ever call this code if you *knew already* that you need to swap the endianess.  If you just called it will nilly it would destroy your data on a little endian machine. So... you'd have to test before calling it. As an aside; your code is wrong.  `+` has higher precedence than `<<`, so you need some parens.

Comment: @EdS. Very well, add the parenthesis in. Please show me which libtiff code you're working on.

Comment: The code above doesn't care about the underlying representation of a uint16_t. Note how I'm stressing *underlying representation of uint16_t*. It'll perform the same regardless of that underlying representation. If the parens are added, the code will perform correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    union {
       uint32_t word;
       uint8_t bytes[4];
    } test_struct;
    test_struct.word = 0x1;
    if (test_struct.bytes[0] != 0)
        printf("little-endian\n");
    else
        printf("big-endian\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On a little-endian architecture, the least significant byte is stored first.  On a big-endian architecture, the most-significant byte is stored first.  So by overlaying a `uint32_t` with a `uint8_t[4]`, I can check to see which byte comes first.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_endian

GCC in particular defines the `__BYTE_ORDER__` macro as an extension.  You can test against `__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__`, `__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__`, and `__ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__` (which I didn't know existed!) -- see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_endian

---

As for running code in an endianness that doesn't match your machine's native endianness, then you're going to have to compile and run it on an architecture that has that different endianness.  So you are going to need to cross-compile, and run on an emulator or virtual machine.

---

**edit**: ah, I didn't see the first `printf()`.

The first `printf` will print "1633837924", since a big-endian machine will interpret the `'a'` character as the most significant byte in the int.

The second `printf` will just print "abcd", since the value of `u` has been copied byte-by-byte back and forth from `i`.

Comment: thanks for yor answer, no, I don't want to know if big endian, I want to run a piece of code under big endian

Comment: Thanks sheu, can you see my edit?

Comment: This program invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidRF: edited some more.

Comment: @sheu The one starting with `int main()`... :P

Comment: @H2CO3: ah well, I don't think there's any behavior actually *undefined* in it, in terms of the C language specification.  Do you see something odd in particular about it?

Comment: @sheu You're accessing an inactive field of a union.

Comment: @H2CO3: you just made me go look up the C99 spec, but I can't find it in the spec.  Do you have a pointer to that?

Comment: Well, the C standard states that "The values of bytes that correspond to union members other than the one last stored
into" is unspecified according to annex J1. In the case of mixed endian systems, or where an underlying bit-pattern of all zeros corresponds to something other than zero, the program above lies.

Comment: Re: Undefined behaviour: There have been machines that added some type bits to data, where storing as one type and trying to access as another would crash the program.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue 6.2.6.2 (5): "For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type". Since both members of the union occupy the same bytes and have no trap representations, there's no undefined behaviour [reading from a member other than the last written to is allowed (footnote 95 to 6.5.2.3 (3) makes that explicit, it was added in a TC to C99)]. The case of a mixed-endian system remains uncovered, however.

Comment: @DanielFischer On an irrelevant note, that statement seems to specify the value of padding bits ;). I was thinking of null pointers when I wrote that comment. My bad. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue It forbids a specific bit pattern to be a trap representation. If there are padding bits in an integer type, the value 0 may have more object representations.