# Is the address of an int the same in little and big endian?

Tags: c, pointers, endianness, memory-address

For example if i have an array of ints.

```
int arr[3] = { 1 , 2 , 3 } ;
unsigned char * a = ( unsigned char* )&arr[0] ;

printf("%d " , *( int* )a ) ;
a += sizeof( int ) ;
printf("%d " , *( int* )a ) ;
a += sizeof( int ) ;
printf("%d " , *( int* )a ) ;
```

Will this code produce `1 2 3` on both big and little endian architecture?

**I'm assuming this holds true for every type including structures?**

Comment: Since the storage i.e. write and subsequent read are as `int` pointers, it should print `1 2 3`. Have you tried this and found a different answer?

Comment: @Ganesh I don't have a big-endian machine.

Comment: The big/little endian aspect of the question also holds for strcutures, extending your example to structures might introduce padding issues however.

Comment: @alk How so, doesn't sizeof take care of that?

Comment: @self.. If you `typecast` a data from one type to another, then you can expect issues if the interpretation of data is not handled properly. Structures should also behave similarly in both architecture including padding considerations. Please check this query for more details on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971369/little-vs-big-endianess-how-to-interpret-the-test

Comment: @alk It would be great if you could expand on padding issues, in an answer if possible.

Comment: Padding is not specific to big or little endian, so you better pose another question on this.

Comment: @alk Can you hint at what kind of padding issue, so I can post a comprehensible question?

Comment: @alk I honestly think there is no padding issue in my code example above and that you a mistaken.

Comment: Please excuse having been unclear. There is **no** padding-issue in the current example code of this question. "*extending your example to structures might introduce padding issues however*" was meant to say that a **similar** example dealing with **structures** **might** introduce padding-issues.

Comment: @alk Thank you , can you give any hint whatsoever on the padding issue or is the issue you are talking about cannot be defined?

Comment: Read an learn about "*padding structures to align its members to certain machine dependend boundaries*" and you understand what I am referring to. 1st hit on gxxgle for the phrase above: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: @alk Thank you for pointing me straight to the obvious answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you're storing int values and then re-retrieving those same int values later then it doesn't matter how they're stored underneath (e.g., big/little endian).

For example, suppose you define

```
int a = 0xaabbccdd;
```

On a little endian system this will be stored as **0xdd 0xcc 0xbb 0xaa** in memory. On a big endian system this will be stored as **0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd**. However, when you view this memory as an **int** it will always be viewed as 0xaabbccdd. Now, if you viewed sub-portions of the original memory (e.g., a sub portion of the int value in memory) endianness would come into play. For example, suppose you only read the first two bytes from the memory location where the int is stored:

```
int *ptr = &a;
short firstTwoBytesInMemory = *(short*)ptr;
```

The value of firstTwoBytesInMemory will be 0xccdd on a little endian system, and 0xaabb on a big endian system.

**Update:**
To extend this further, structs are essentially collections of primitive types (e.g., bytes, ints, pointers to other things, etc.). These primitive types are usually laid out in memory contiguously (with some exceptions for alignment, etc). So the same rules that apply to the int/short example above apply to collections of primitive types (e.g., structs).

If you start accessing sub-portions of variables then the endianness of the architecture will matter, but if you always deal with things in their correct types (e.g., int, double, etc.) in their entirety the way things are stored underneath should be transparent.

Comment: @Klas He's casting bytes in memory to ints (on the same int boundaries that the original data was constructed)

Comment: It's not "viewed with the MSB first", it's viewed with the MSB most significantly! There isn't a "first" or "last" about the bytes inside the int, it's just an int - it could be stored in absolutely any way the architecture chooses (eg interleaving digits in some crazy way).

Comment: That's true, what I was trying to say (perhaps in a not very clear way) is that if you store ints and then read them later as ints on the same int boundaries that you created them on you'll always get the same values. However, if you start reading portions of the original data what you will get will depend on how the architecture stores its memory.

Comment: If the ints are stored on disk or sent over a network to a machine with the opposite endianess, you will need to account for the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct.
on a given architecture, endianess problem will not occur unless you explicitly use endianess conversion functions to modify a value.
endianess problem occurs when you exchange information between LE and BE architecture (usually a PC and a portable device).
in your case, you convert int* to (unsigned char*), and convert (unsigned char*) back to (int*) which does not affect the actual data (the int array's content) when then pointer is dereferenced. the conversion is made on pointer, not on the int itself.